# Minimum iframe size to avoid scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display an iframe, which can be pointed to various urls, and would like to dynamically resize it to display its contents without a scrollbar.

How can I find those dimensions?

Comment: Cross-site isn't a problem: all the HTML is same-site.

I'm just trying to avoid tweaking for each, or precalculating, hoping this is something already available.

Comment: Best I've got so far:

jQuery("body").height()
jQuery("body").width()

Comment: those are exactly what you need.

Comment: They work great for FF,  but height is wrong in IE :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  Many sites resize their content to fit their container, so resizing the container to fit the content will be messy at best.  Additionally, due to the single-origin policy, JavaScript won't be able to inspect the page loaded in the iframe if it comes from another site, so I don't think you'll even be able to tell if it needs to scroll or not.

You could approximate it by calculating the dimensions ahead of time, but even then it would only be a guess, since the exact size of objects in the browser is controlled only by the browser.  If the user has picked a large font size, for example, there may be no size you can expand the iframe to that will be big enough for the user to see the entire page without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it by communicating between the iframe and your website. This is the technique OpenSocial gadgets use for example. This is only possible if both the iframe and the parent are under control, in which case you can use HTML5 [cross-window messaging](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage) and [fall back to other cross-domain hacks](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) if the browser can't deal with that.

You could also try to avoid the iframe by pulling the site directly and serving its content. That would only be possible for a very limited number of sites, mostly just static sites, and even then, not ideal by any means.